# Problem launching world files using roslaunch

Tags: gazebo, roslaunch, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to launch a world file using roslaunch and running into errors. I am working with ROS kinetic and gazebo-7.
My ultimate goal is to open a custom world made with the world plugin, and spawn a urdf into that world.

I have been using roslaunch to start an empty world with the following launch file, and that has worked fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<launch>
    <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    </include>
</launch>
```

However, when I try to use the examples found in the [Gazebo Ros tutorials](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_roslaunch) to launch another world file, the execution fails.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<launch>
    
    <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
        <arg name="world_name" value="mud.world"/> 
        <arg name="debug" value="true"/> 
    </include>
</launch>
```

Results in the error below:

```
   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::lock_error> >'
  what():  boost: mutex lock failed in pthread_mutex_lock: Invalid argument
terminate called recursively

Thread 18 "gzserver" received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
```

The result is that the gazebo window opens but never loads any world, it simply stays at a black screen.

Note: I have already put the gazebo worlds directory in my .bashrc and I have tried apt-get update and apt-get upgrade.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/365933/problem-launching-world-files-using-roslaunch/) by [rmmilner](https://answers.ros.org/users/56537/rmmilner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2020-11-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2020-11-19**:
By no means this will be a "solution", but a potential workaround https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15138/need-help-with-error-when-launch-gazebo-first-time/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solution was a simple syntax error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<launch>
    
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="worlds/mud.world"/> 
  </include>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [rmmilner](https://answers.ros.org/users/56537/rmmilner/) with karma: 11 on 2020-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0